# Find first char occurrence in a string without using array or picking a letter manually

Tags: java

I've looked through the posts but couldn't find the exact answer. This is the code i have. it only returns a value when i set s.CharAt(0) and then h will equal h. Bu t i want it to run automatically and w/o arrays.

```
String s = "hellohe";
int d = s.length();

for (int i =0; i<d;i++)//{
   char result=s.charAt(0);

if (result==s.charAt(i)) {
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Comment: Your question is a little unclear. I can see how it can result in `h` because that *is* the first `char` that will have a repeated instance. However, `l` could also be valid, since it is the first `char` that actually repeats.

Comment: Hi, Summet just have answered my question. Thanks anyway!

Comment: had you clarified what you meant I would've given you the answer as soon as you posted it. Anyways, cheers!

Comment: i just saw your answer! thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I propose a much cleaner solution with a method:

```
public static char getFirstReocurringCharacter(String s) {
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length(); i++) {
        for (int j = i + 1; j < s.length(); j++) {
            if (s.charAt(i) == s.charAt(j)) {
                return s.charAt(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return ' ';
}
```

That you can call with:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "heasellohe";
    char result = getFirstReocurringCharacter(s);
    System.out.println(result);
}
```

Sample run:

> run: 
>   h 
>   BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)

Now you can call and run the method multiple times on different `Strings`

Comment: Hi Ceelos, i still have  a question% can you please let me know how loops above work? i'm trying compare....ile 0-->h,h--->e, e-->l, l==l?

Comment: @miami_oleg the outer loop will iterate through each letter. The inner loop will iterate through each letter after the letter that the outer loop is on. So the first comparison is between `h` and `e`. The inner loop returns when both the outer loop and inner loop match with respect to the letter they're on.

Comment: but when outer loop will be on L, inner loop will be also on L... am i right? if yes, then this should be first reoccurence?

Comment: or do you mean, that outer loop will keep h while inner loop will iterate through e,l,l,o, and will stop on h?

Comment: @miami_oleg For the first iteration, the outer loop will be on `h`. The inner loop will start at `e`, and since it doesn't match will continue onto `a` then `e` and so on until it reaches the last `h`, at which point the outer loop and inner loop match so it will return `h`.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT:
This would print the first reocurring character using back references ([source](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/regex/groups.html)) and look ahead, so in the following case it prints 'h' :

```
String myString = "hellohe";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(([a-zA-Z]).*?(?=\\2))");
Matcher m = p.matcher(myString);
m.find();
System.out.println(m.group(2));
```

Comment: thanks, but why won't it return H as it is the first reocurring letter?